# how to configure csp in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, content-security-policy, nuxt.js

Currently I just use nuxt.js  for my thesis work. The code just pop a error tackles in csp.

I do the basic configuration in nuxt.config.js and revert my code back. It still pop up.

> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). Source: ;!function(){var t,e,n,o=0,u=function(t,....
>
> Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at self (“default-src”). Source: call to eval() or related function
> blocked by CSP.

Is there a basic configuration about this.

Answer (score 1):

What's the basic config that you've got for the Content Security Policy?

I've found that setting your own CSP configuration in your `nuxt.config.js` file almost always causes that error, which seems a bit strange.

Obviously in production you'd definitely want to flesh this out a bit more, but if you're just doing your project in development mode, then I wouldn't worry about configuring your own CSP (unless it's required of course).